# issue with qtp 10 and IE8

Tags: qtp

I'm not able to open IE8 when my QTP 10 is open.  When I try to open it, it opens and closes immediately,but if i close QTP then I'm able to open IE then it opens normally. why does this happen, whats the solution?

Answer (score 0):

The original version of QTP10 did not support IE8. Did you install the [release update](http://support.openview.hp.com/selfsolve/document/KM777646) (which contains support for IE8)?

Comment: the problem is that, I'm facing the same problem with IE6 also. Only in two machines this problem is there, there are other machines where both IE6 and IE8 have been used and it is working fine there.

Comment: @Tom, any idea what makes those two machines special?